# C# infinite loop when using SkipWhile

Tags: c#, loops

i'm trying to achieve the same result of the first example in example B

Class Numbers:

```
class Numbers: IEnumerable<int>
{
    public IEnumerator<int> GetEnumerator()
    {
        int count = 1;
        while (true)
        {
            count *= 2;
            yield return count * 2;
        }
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return GetEnumerator();
    }
}
```

Where example in Main: Number should be greater than 10 and lower than 1000

```
Numbers r = new Numbers();
var result = r.Where(i => i > 10 && i < 1000);
foreach (var VARIABLE in result)
{
    Console.WriteLine(VARIABLE);
}
```

Second example with SkipWhile (Not working)

```
var intset = r.SkipWhile(i => i < 10 || i > 1000);
foreach (var VARIABLE in intset)
{
    Console.WriteLine(VARIABLE);
}
```

The second example is causing an infinite loop. It starts at 16 but keep printing 0;

Any idea what i'm doing wrong?

**EDIT**:

I found a solution for this problem. By combining SkipWhile with TakeWhile it works.

```
var intset = r2.SkipWhile(i => i < 10).TakeWhile(z => z < 1000);
```

Comment: Changing AND operator to OR isn't working aswell

Comment: You're right, i just noticed that. But if i change the operator to OR, makes no differents

Comment: Where is `i` changing? If the condition is true and then `i` doesn't change then the condition will keep being true.

Comment: Read the documentation for `SkipWhile`. It **skips** so and so many elements **until** the predicate (your lambda expression) becomes false. Given that your Numbers enumerator is providing an infinite sequence of numbers, why do you expect the loop not to be infinite? (Skipping a finite amount of numbers in an infinite sequence still leaves you with an infinite sequence) I think you misunderstand fundamentally what SkipWhile does, hence why i suggest you look up and read its documentation...

Comment: It's because you are using the same result set twice. If you create a new `r` before the second example, it will work.

Comment: @ckuri It does not skip every value greater than 1000 in the sequence.  That would be `Where`, not `SkipWhile`.

Comment: @RonBeyer `Numbers` has no instance level state, so it will always yield exactly the same values each time it's iterated over, whether using the same instance or a new one.

Comment: @Servy Yes it does, the `count` variable is an instance level state.

Comment: @ScottHannen `i` is the current value in the sequence.  It changes every time it's evaluating the predicate against the next value in the sequence.

Comment: @RonBeyer That's a local variable, not a field, so no.  It's not shared between invocations of the method.  Note that you can see this for yourself by just running the code, no need to take my word for it.

Comment: @RonBeyer Even with a new r you'll get same result.

Comment: @Servy Because of the `yield return...` the method is only ever invoked once, but the `while` loop keeps returning each time the method is called again (it continues after the `yield`). So it does preserve `count`.

Comment: @RonBeyer The method is invoked as many times as you invoke it.  If you invoke it once, there's one enumerator with the count state.  If you invoke it twice there's two, each with their own count (which is initialized to `1`).  All invocations of the method don't just magically all return the same enumerator (unless you write code that specifically does that, which is not done here).  Again, you can just run the code and see for yourself that `count` is in fact local to each iterator, and isn't shared between all iterators returned from that object.

Comment: Does this mean that there is no solution for this without editing GetEmurerator()

Comment: Note that while it is true that the `count` variable eventually rolls over, producing an infinite number of zeros, it still is an infinite sequence. Thus the foreach loop either loops infinitely, or SkipWhile will be stuck attempting to skip an infinite amount of elements from an infinite sequence until the universe dies a cold, dark death...

Comment: @J.Adam Solution to what?  You say you just want the behavior of your first solution.  If so, then *use that solution*, rather than the one that doesn't work.

Comment: Note that also the first solution in the question (using Where) will result in an infinite loop or freeze (here the latter, because the Number enumerator eventually degrades to churn out an infinite amount of zeros), because the foreach loop will make it evaluate **every** element in an infinite sequence.

Comment: @Servy I thought it was also possible with SkipWhile that's why i asked it here.

Comment: @elganzo The first example works fine, you can try it out. All the code is there.

Comment: @J.Adam, no, it is not working fine! Place a Console.WriteLine **after** the foreach loop and see whether your code will ever execute it. You just think it works fine because you don't see it not outputting anything anymore (which is not because it is "fine", but because it gets stuck and frozen in the .Where() which forever until eternity is looking at an unending parade of zeros)

Comment: @J.Adam Why do you need to use `SkipWhile` to perform a `Where` operation when you have `Where` to perform a `Where` operation?

Comment: Can you please post a *complete* [mcve] for the second example with SkipWhile? I ask because it doesn't start with 16 for me, so I am assuming you're doing something different.

Comment: @J.Adam, you can actually quite easily observe the problematic behavior youself by using the [amazing step debugger in Visual Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/visualstudio/debugger/navigating-through-code-with-the-debugger)

Comment: @LasseVagsaetherKarlsen It should start at 16.

Comment: @J.Adam - Please don't put the answer at the end of your question. Please post it as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you used up the result set.

```
class Numbers: IEnumerable<int>
{
    public IEnumerator<int> GetEnumerator()
    {
        int count = 1;
        while (true)
        {
            count *= 2;
            yield return count * 2;
        }
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return GetEnumerator();
    }
}
```

When you multiply `count *= 2` you will eventually exceed the size of the `int` variable type, and eventually, after -2147483648 is returned you get 0 for the `count`, which multiplied by 2 is always 0.

So now when you use it in your second example, all it will ever return is 0.

Here is the result set for the first time:

```
16
32
64
128
256
512
1024
2048
4096
8192
16384
32768
65536
131072
262144
524288
1048576
2097152
4194304
8388608
16777216
33554432
67108864
134217728
268435456
536870912
1073741824
-2147483648
0
0
0 ...
```

So either you have to reset the `Numbers` somehow, or handle the roll over.

The other issue you have is how [`SkipWhile`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.skipwhile?view=netframework-4.8) works:

> Bypasses elements in a sequence as long as a specified condition is true and **then returns the remaining elements**.

So it will skip everything below 10 (the next number is 16), but because something now matches the predicate it will return *all* the remaining results, even those above 1000.

Comment: Thank you Ron. I didn't know this.

Comment: I understand now how it works. But still i'm a bit confused because i got two conditions inside SkipWhile()

Comment: Because the condition was satisfied after `i > 10` so then it returns **all** the remaining elements.

Comment: Well ye, that's true